# Youtube Data API - display private videos in a React Native app programmatically

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

What I want to do:

- display videos from a client in a RN app. They keep them as private YT videos and only want to give access to paid users via a mobile app.

Apparently, after a few tests, an API key is not enough for that, as I get only the public videos.
I could get the private videos and playlists back using Oauth2 authentication, in Google OAuth2 playground.

Where I am lost is, how to programmatically get the authorization code, then the access and refresh token, on app startup, to attach them to the requests.

Every tutorial I find is about implementing it via the consent screen to authenticate a user.

I don't want to use a consent screen, I got the clients username/password already and just would like to authenticate in the background as the app starts.

Any good resources/tips out there to help me figure this out? Thank you.